# I keep getting invalid parameter number: number or bound variables does not math number of tokens in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, yii2

I am doing a simple update in yii2 controller inside of a for loop. When doing so I keep getting sql error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

My code is below:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $existingProductCount; $x++)
        {
            $connection = Yii::$app->db;
            $params = [
                ':idcampaign_products' => intval(Yii::$app->request->post("idcampaign_product")[$x]),
                ':existing_products' => intval(Yii::$app->request->post("dynamicExistingProducts")[$x]),
                ':existing_billing_cycle' => Yii::$app->request->post("dynamicExistingBillingCycle")[$x],
                ':existing_trial_length' => Yii::$app->request->post("dynamicExistingTrialLength")[$x],
                ':existing_trial_price' => Yii::$app->request->post("dynamicExistingTrialPrice")[$x],
                ':existing_reg_price' => Yii::$app->request->post("dynamicExistingRegPrice")[$x]
            ];
            $connection->createCommand()
            ->update('campaign_products',
                [
                    'product_id'=>$params[':existing_products'],
                    'campaign_billing_cycle'=>$params[':existing_billing_cycle'],
                    'trial_length'=>$params[':existing_trial_length'],
                    'trial_price'=>$params[':existing_trial_price'],
                    'regular_price'=>$params[':existing_reg_price']
                ],
                'idcampaign_products=:idcampaign_products')
            ->bindValues($params)
            ->execute();
            //var_dump($params);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing this properly. When you use query builder with an array you don't have to bound values - it's done automatically. With your code only `:idcampaign_products` needs to be bound and since you pass 6 values that is why the error pops.

Do it like that:

```
$connection->createCommand()
    ->update('campaign_products', [
        'product_id' => $params[':existing_products'],
        'campaign_billing_cycle' => $params[':existing_billing_cycle'],
        'trial_length' => $params[':existing_trial_length'],
        'trial_price' => $params[':existing_trial_price'],
        'regular_price' => $params[':existing_reg_price']
    ], ['idcampaign_products' => $params[':idcampaign_products']])
    ->execute();
```

Comment: That's weird because in the error it gives me the output of the query:
UPDATE `campaign_products` SET `product_id`=19, `campaign_billing_cycle`=30, `trial_length`=16, `trial_price`='44.00', `regular_price`='56.00' WHERE idcampaign_products=13
Which works when I run it in mysql workbench. Also you say idcampaign_products need to be the only one bound but I don't see you using the bindvalue command

Comment: The output in the query is already processed so everything is on its place. As for the one param bound check again your code like it was before but this time replace `->bindValues($params)` with `->bindValues([':idcampaign_products' => intval(Yii::$app->request->post("idcampaign_product")[$x])])` so only this value is bound.